# Error: could not convert string to float in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read two columns of data, `Mean` and `Std` from the file `Mean.Std.txt`. But I am running into an error which I have shown below. I also present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

Mean,Std = np.loadtxt('Mean_Std.txt',unpack=True)
print([Mean])
print([Std])
```

The data in `Mean_Std.txt` looks like

```
Mean              Std
41.96969696969697 0.22727272727273018
29.646464646464647 2.3263867473915276
24.444444444444443 2.836612913158948
22.424242424242426 3.2698851295313993
21.262626262626263 3.4897856988730362
20.80808080808081 4.038667556139951
20.606060606060606 4.342039357850636
20.606060606060606 4.342039357850636
20.606060606060606 4.342039357850636
20.606060606060606 4.342039357850636
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Sept17_2022\220\var_1_beta_1e-1\Test.py", line 19, in <module>
    Mean,Std = np.loadtxt('Mean_Std.txt',unpack=True)

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1146, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 997, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 997, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 734, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Mean'
```

The expected output is

```
[array([41.96969697, 29.64646465, 24.44444444, 22.42424242, 21.26262626,
       20.80808081, 20.60606061, 20.60606061, 20.60606061, 20.60606061])]
[array([0.22727273, 2.32638675, 2.83661291, 3.26988513, 3.4897857 ,
       4.03866756, 4.34203936, 4.34203936, 4.34203936, 4.34203936])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `skiprows=1` to skip header row

```
Mean,Std = np.loadtxt('Mean_Std.txt',unpack=True, skiprows=1)
print([Mean])
print([Std])
```

```
[array([41.96969697, 29.64646465, 24.44444444, 22.42424242, 21.26262626,
       20.80808081, 20.60606061, 20.60606061, 20.60606061, 20.60606061])]
[array([0.22727273, 2.32638675, 2.83661291, 3.26988513, 3.4897857 ,
       4.03866756, 4.34203936, 4.34203936, 4.34203936, 4.34203936])]
```